# Event causing an infinite loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a static event which is triggered whenever the player clicks the Left-Click Button.

I have a list of gameobjects that are listening to this event, however the function that is supposed to execute ONLY when `ableToShoot` is `true`.

Seems to execute even if it is false. I do have a function which calls a function which makes the next object's from the list `ableToShoot = true`,
however this seems to put it in an infinite loop.

This is the LeftClickEvent Script.

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void ShootProjectile();
    public static event ShootProjectile Shoot;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if (Shoot != null)
                {
                    Shoot();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (Shoot != null)
            {
                Shoot();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Script that is listening to the LeftClickEvent :

```
public class ProjectileMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 3;
    private bool ableToShoot;
    public int itemInList = 0;
    public StartLevelMechanics mechanics;
    HitParticles particles;

    public bool AbleToShoot
    {
        get
        {
            return ableToShoot;
        }

        set
        {
            ableToShoot = value;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        InputManager.Shoot += ShootProjectile;
        particles = GameObject.Find("HitParticles").GetComponent<HitParticles>();
        AbleToShoot = false;
    }

    public void ShootProjectile()
    {
        if (AbleToShoot)
        {
            GetComponentInChildren<Animator>().SetTrigger("Shoot");
            iTween.MoveTo(this.gameObject, iTween.Hash("position", new Vector3(transform.position.x, 10, transform.position.z),
                          "easetype", iTween.EaseType.spring, "time", 1f, "oncomplete", "DestroyProjectile",  "oncompletetarget", 
                          this.gameObject));
            mechanics.NewBall();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the mechanics script which turns the next gameobjects AbleToShoot to true.

```
public void NewBall()
{
    if (projectiles.Count == 1)
    {
        projectiles.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        projectiles.Remove(projectiles[0]);
    }

    if (projectiles.Count == 0)
    {
        levelOver();
        return;
    }

    lastBall = projectiles[0];
    ProjectileMovement movement = lastBall.GetComponent<ProjectileMovement>();

    iTween.MoveTo(lastBall, iTween.Hash("position", ShootStartPosition,
                  "time", 0.3f, "easetype", iTween.EaseType.easeOutQuad));
    RotateBalls();
    AbleToShoot();
    return;
}
```

So I get the feeling that the event is somehow put to a queue which executes whenever `AbleToShoot == true`, however I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Where is it setting it to `true`? I see you have `AbleToShoot();` which is attempting to call a property like a method (and you should be getting an error). I don't see anywhere that you say `AbleToShoot = true;`...

Comment: Or setting it to `false` again for that matter. When you say infinite loop, do you mean that your unity editor freezes?

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't freeze. It stops when the list is empty.

AbleToShoot just sets the lastBall.AbleToShoot to true, nothing more.

Comment: There's no loop so it can't be getting stuck (I recommend updating your title, too).  Did you intend for *all* projectiles to be fired in the one `Shoot` call?

Comment: `So I get the feeling that the event is somehow put to a queue which executes whenever AbleToShoot == true, however I could not find anything in the documentation` .. which documentation?

Comment: @Immersive No, that's the thing i don't want to happen.

Comment: @SimonasHolcmann I don't have access to Visual Studio at the moment, I'll write up a proper answer when I get back home tomorrow.  Basically, the problem is your use of the `event Shoot`.  Replace that with a list/queue and you'll be good.

Comment: eg `Queue<Action> Shoot`  then `var oneShot = Shoot.Pop();  oneShot();`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because it creating multiple copies of the class. Without knowing where else it is used, this is just a guess. Try changing it so there is only ever one copy of the variable ableToShoot:

```
private static bool ableToShoot;
```

Comment: I need each object to have this property, so it is not an option.